# sizeof and types, guarantees

Tags: c++, sizeof, alignof

I cannot find a proof/disproof that the following code snippet has no design flaws, speaking about the correctness.

```
template <class Item>
class MyDirtyPool {
public:
    template<typename ... Args>
    std::size_t add(Args &&... args) {

        if (!m_deletedComponentsIndexes.empty()) {
            //reuse old block
            size_t positionIndex = m_deletedComponentsIndexes.back();
            m_deletedComponentsIndexes.pop_back();
            void *block = static_cast<void *> (&m_memoryBlock[positionIndex]);
            new(block) Item(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);

            return positionIndex;
        } else {
            //not found, add new block
            m_memoryBlock.emplace_back();

            void *block = static_cast<void *> (&m_memoryBlock.back());
            new(block) Item(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);

            return m_memoryBlock.size() - 1;
        }
    }
    //...all the other methods omitted
private:
    struct Chunk {
        char mem[sizeof(Item)]; //is this sane?
    };

    std::vector<Chunk> m_memoryBlock; //and this one too, safe?
    std::deque<std::size_t> m_deletedComponentsIndexes;
};
```

I am concerned about all the stuff with Chunk, which is used here in essence as a bag of memory having the same size as the supplied type.
I don't want to explicitly create Item objects in the `m_memoryBlock`, therefore I need some kind of "chunk of memory having enough of space".

Can I be sure that Chunk will have the same size as the supplied type? Please provide some examples where this assumption won't work.

If I am totally wrong in my assumptions, how should I deal with it?

Comment: This is perfectly valid approach (aligning notwithstanding). `Chunk` is guaranteed to be at least the size of `Item` (might be more).

Comment: Are you asking if `sizeof(Chunk) == sizeof(Item)`?

Comment: Why not use [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) instead of `Chunk`?

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, will it work for *all* different `Item`s? what if I have a derived class for example?

Comment: This isn't safe. The vector might reallocate memory without correctly moving its contents.

Comment: @Cornstalks in my design here I perform only additions, no removes.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The vector will reallocate when its `size` exceeds its `capacity`. When it does so, it will not correctly move the its contents or destroy its old contents (unless `Item` is trivially copyable/movable/destructable).

Comment: what does 'not correctly move its contents or destroy its old contents' mean?

Comment: @varnie: The `std::vector<Chunk>`  will move elements using `Chunk::Chunk(Chunk&&)` not `Item::Item(Item&&)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such designs the memory must be suitably aligned for the type of objects you would like to create there.

Standard built-in types normally have *natural* alignment, which equals to their `sizeof`, i.e. `sizeof(T) == alignof(T)`.

The alignment of `char` array is 1 byte, which is insufficient for anything else.

One simple way to enforce alignment is to use [`std::max_align_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/max_align_t) like this:

```
union Chunk 
{
    std::max_align_t max_align;
    char mem[sizeof(Item)]; 
};
```

That will make `Chunk::mem` suitably aligned for any standard built-in type.

---

Another way is to use the exact alignment of the type you would like to place in that `char` array using C++11 [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) keyword:

```
struct Chunk 
{
    alignas(Item) char mem[sizeof(Item)]; 
};
```

And this is exactly what [`std::aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) does for you.

However, that would require exposing the definition of `Item`, which may be inconvenient or undesirable in some cases.

For example, this method could be used as an optimization for [Pimpl idiom](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/) to avoid a memory allocation, however, that would require exposing the definition of the implementation in the header file to get its size and alignment, therefore defeating the purpose of Pimpl. See [The Fast Pimpl Idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm) for more details.

---

Another detail, is that if you would like to copy/move `Chunk`s and expect the stored objects to remain valid, those stored objects must be [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable), e.g.

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Item>::value, 
              "Item cannot be copied byte-wise");
typedef std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Item), alignof(Item)> Chunk;
```

---

For a memory pool `std::vector<Chunk>` is not a good choice because on reallocation when the vector grows all pointers and references to the objects stored in the pool get invalidated.

The objects should not move in a general memory pool.

Comment: thank you for such thorough answer! could you explain a bit more this: "which may be inconvenient or undesirable in some cases"?

Comment: btw, shouldn't it be `typedef std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Item), alignof(Item)>::type Chunk`?

Comment: hmm..what if I use non trivially copyable classes and yet want to use `std::aligned_storage` approach? now I am a bit confused.

Comment: @varnie: Possible, but dangerous. You can't rely on vector to grow and relocate. Any operation that would cause vector to grow past `capacity` would require you to create a new vector of the desired size with sufficient extra capacity, call the move ctor of `Item` (or failing that, the copy ctor followed by the dtor), swap the two vectors, and then call the dtor on all `Item`'s in the vector you just swapped out. If that doesn't make sense, you probably don't know C++ well enough to design such containers. Because I haven't even mentioned exceptions yet.